# Angular 6 Reactive forms Validators.minLength

Tags: angular, validation

This one might be a fresh-eye look or something horribly wrong from my side.

I am trying to create dynamic forms via json. For that purpose, I have created a separate Input component, which works as expected; however, when I try to add minLength validator, it bombs with message

**Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.**

```
ngOnInit() {
    const formControl = this.group.controls[this.config.name];

    // if (this.config.validation.required) {
    //  this.validators.push(Validators.required);
    //  formControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    // }

    if (this.config.validation.minLength) {
        this.validators.push(Validators.minLength(this.config.validation.minLength));
        formControl.setValidators([Validators.minLength(this.config.validation.minLength)]);
    }

    formControl.setValue(null);
    formControl.updateValueAndValidity();

    console.log(this.group.controls[this.config.name].validator(formControl));
    this.ready = true;


}
```

The commented code for required validator works fine; however, as soon as I add minLength it throws the mentioned error.

Also, whether I add updateValueAndValiditiy() or not, it still fails.

*Please note: config settings are being read from JSON*

Comment: Read more about the error here https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and break-points settings, the problem was found somewhere else and of course, my analysis was wrong, when I posted this question.

In my JSON, there was a node for validation, which I completely missed for "dropdown" component, and error was bubbling up to be what the question says; however, on further digging, it was occuring during setting of validations.